# How can I make my Visual Studio look like this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-express

[image]

My eyes kind of burn when I code for too long and this will definitely help  me sooth them. I would ask this in SuperUser but there are few people from the dev world there. Mostly Windows Vista/7 savvy people.

I know someone can help me out here. :D

Thanks SO!

Comment: Ahh, if only Visual Studio always looked like Python.

Comment: Burning eyes == bad. Have you considered visiting an optometrist?

Comment: Seth: Maybe you'd be interested in Boo: http://boo.codehaus.org/

Comment: Quick warning. When you change your default color scheme (especially background color) just be aware that when you copy your code to a RTF aware app (like email) the background will travel with it. This can be a little annoying when sharing syntax highlighted code with others.

Comment: @GrayWizardx: use "Paste Special" and "Unformatted text" to avoid that sort of nonsense.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up Gray.

Comment: "Paste Special" as unformatted text will also remove any syntax highlighting.

Comment: Any link to a full screenshot of that Papuccino1?  I wouldn't mind trying to emulate it, looks like a nice theme.

Answer (score 3):

You can just customize the settings to do this.

Many people have made dark "themes" such as this, and have the settings exported (so you can directly import them).

Here is [one example](http://www.notimplementedexception.com/visual-studio-settings-files/).

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I liked the looks of your screenshot so much that I went ahead and created a theme out of it:

[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/4305/pondscumtheme.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/4305/pondscumtheme.png)

You can download the .vssettings file [off my blog](http://www.phpvs.net/vs-themes/), and import the settings in Visual Studio using Tools -> Import and Export Settings.

If you can provide any more information on where you got that screenshot, I'd love to credit the original.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the settings in:

tools > options > environment > fonts and colors

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, you'll need to customize your Visual Studio settings.

If you're interested, I have a [Visual Studio dark theme](http://www.raregrooverider.com/post/2009/05/10/Visual-Studio-Dark-Side-Theme-for-Resharper.aspx) that is similar to your pic (works with ReSharper as well).

Answer (score 0):

Write code in [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) and use this [Wombat color scheme port for Visual Studio](http://www.mohundro.com/blog/2008/01/11/MyAttemptAtConvertingTheVIMWombatThemeToSupportVisualStudio.aspx) ;)

Answer (score -1):

You can use themes. A good post on that can be found [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/VisualStudioProgrammerThemesGallery.aspx)